# How can I get the path of a batch file as a variable?

Tags: batch-file, path, cmd

How can I get the path of a batch file as a variable?

So for example, I found I can use `%cd%` to get the directory of the batch fie that is currently executing, but if I call a second batch file from the first, `%cd%` in the second file will point to the directory of the first file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being mistaken here. As the documentation (`help set`) clearly states,

```
%CD% - expands to the current directory string.
```

So it's not the directory of the batch file, it's the current working directory, same as `$pwd` in PowerShell. It *might* be the directory of the currently-executing batch file, but only if your current directory is the same.

What you want is `%~dp0` instead, which evalutes to the drive and path of the invocation, i.e. your batch file.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks for the quick reply. I have found this rather confusing - the difference between the current working directory and the directory of the currently executing batch file.

Comment: Every process has a current working directory. In shells, that's what you alter with `cd`, `pushd`, `popd` and the like. Changing the current working directory does not move files around, nor does executing programs or batch files elsewhere intrinsically change the current working directory. You can start a batch file from `C:\` by typing `D:\foo.cmd` and the working directory will still be `C:\`, even though the batch file's directory is elsewhere.